# What is the most efficient way to select points from inside a path

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, computational-geometry

Having a path, for example: [image: map of guatemala]

composed of a set of points 'p'

I have a set of randomly placed points, both inside and outside. called 'n'

[image: crudely placed points]

So to compare all the points inside to the points on the path to the random points, would be probably exponentially complex. Something like <s>O(n) = n^p if I'm not mistaken</s>  It's O(n) = n*p

So to solve the problem I am thinking that you could subdivide the path in a minimum area that is completely outside, and other that is completely inside. as in the figure

[image]

The green set would be inside, the black outside and the orange to be iterated again several times

[image]

Is this possible, and more importantly, is it efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider looking at point-in-polygon testing literature.

With this large number of points, I can imagine a y-sweeping approach to be sensible and efficient. Much more than this iteration thing you are trying to do.

Comment: In any case, the complexity is O(np) not O(n^p).

Comment: Thanks, That was exactly what I was looking for. I will read on the topic, seems an interesting subject to study.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, its possible.  But without any idea of how costly it is to FIND these regions, nor how costly it is to partition the points into inside & outside, there's no way to evaluate its efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

A sampling-based approach may be your best bet. Not a particle filter but the same sort of idea. Sequential Monte Carlo method is something to look into also.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Essentenially, take a random sampling of the points and test if they are inside or outside to build your map. Repeat the sample method a number of times until you have a good enough map. You can adjust the number of samples and number of repeats to balance both efficiency and result.

Answer (score 0):

A similar (i.e., geometric rather than spatial) approach might be to first use a convex hull to exclude points that are definitely *outside* the path.

Then, recursively decompose the path into subpaths which are not on the hull (call them "concavities"), and apply the same convex hull approach to them.  You will end up with a tree of regions (each bounded by the convex hull at its root), such that all children are to be subtracted from the convex bound defined by their parent.

Unfortunately, this alone will not guarantee an efficient query (as there is no upper bound on either the depth or the number of children of a particular node; also note that the child bounds can overlap even if the path does not...).  You will still need some form of acceleration structure -- but that should be significantly easier now that your regions are convex.

Answer (score 0):

What is the original representation of your path? implicit function? parametric? bitmap? polyline?... the answer varies greatly depending on this

Comment: I mentioned having the path as a set of points, such as a polygon.General advice and where to look for the other forms would be appreciated as well.